# Auto BCC Microsoft Outlook 2011 using Applescript

Tags: applescript, bcc, outlook-2011

I have been searching the past few days and with no luck trying to find a solution.

My company is trying to us a CRM system which tracks e-mails. I want to automatically BCC e-mails to contacts in certain categories.

Since it is impossible for rules to do this, I was trying to find an applescript that could accomplish this.

I am not familiar with applescript and quite frankly dissapointed with how dumb down Microsoft Outlook is for Macs.

Could anyone provide me with a script to help me accomplish automatically BCC when "Replying" or creating a "New-Email" of people in specific categories? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution and I made an AppleScript to do this:

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

```
set newMessage to make new outgoing message
make new bcc recipient at newMessage with properties {email address:{name:"Name", address:"someone@bccsalesforce.com"}}

open newMessage
```

end tell

Give It a whirl.just remember to replace Name and someone@bccsalesforce.com with the correct ones. Also Make sure to create a Contact with the bcc email to match the name and address.

Comment: [1/3] I tried looking through the outlook applescript dictionary for more insight, but I'm not experienced enough with applescript to parse in my head what I need to do... so, **do you have any idea how to append a bcc to an outgoing message?**

Comment: [2/3] It would appear that I can ***only*** trigger the applescript to run ***while coming in or going out***, not on other actions, via rules. Are you aware of how I could make one of my accounts always bcc itself (or a predetermined address which would be the same)? any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [3/3] *Apparently, MS Outlook 2016 does this as a setting, but only to the default account, which is not where I'd want it to go anyway. Plus, I'm stuck on OS 10.9 for some other legacy software, so I'm basically trying to get MSO2011 to behave the way Apple's Mail.app can with a single preferences checkbox for well over a decade.*

Thanks in advance...